# Accessing authenticated route with vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

Ive been struggling with a bug that occurs occasionally within my VueJs2 application.

After i login and im authenticated within my app and data is stored within Vuex then im unable to access an authenticated route when clicking on the link.

The problem is with the 'profile' route which is on my navbar when logged in. If i refresh the browser then it works and im able to click the link and view the component. 
The problem is with the beforeEach and it failing to get the Vuex authenticated as true.

This is my current router setup.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { store } from '../store/index'

import SiteIndex from '@/components/home/Index.vue'
import AuctionIndex from '@/components/auction/Index.vue'
import ViewVehicle from '@/components/vehicle/View.vue'
import Login from '@/components/authentication/Login.vue'
import Register from '@/components/registration/Register.vue'
import ForgotPassword from '@/components/authentication/Forgot.vue'
import Cart from '@/components/cart/Index.vue'

import UserProfile from '@/components/user/Profile.vue'
import AboutUs from '@/components/site/About.vue'
import Faq from '@/components/site/Faq.vue'
import HowItWorks from '@/components/site/HowItWorks.vue'
import ContactUs from '@/components/site/ContactUs.vue'
import Terms from '@/components/site/Terms.vue'

import Error404 from '@/components/site/Error404.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/index' },
    { path: '/logout', redirect: '/login' },
    {
        path: '/index',
        name: 'home',
        component: SiteIndex,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: 'Home',
            displayBreadCrumb:false
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/auction',
        name: 'auction',
        component: AuctionIndex,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Auction',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/auction/:slug/:vehicle_id',
        component: ViewVehicle,
        meta: {
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/cart',
        component: Cart,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Basket',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Login',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        component: Register,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Register',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/forgot',
        component: ForgotPassword,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Forgot Password',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/profile',
        component: UserProfile,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'My Profile',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/terms',
        component: Terms,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Terms and conditions',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/howitworks',
        component: HowItWorks,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'How it works',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/faq',
        component: Faq,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Frequently asked questions',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: AboutUs,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'About us',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/contactus',
        component: ContactUs,
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: {
                label: 'Contact us',
                parent: 'home'
            },
            displayBreadCrumb:true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: Error404
    }
  ],
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'history'
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if(requiresAuth && !store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: Are you redirected to `login` page when you click on `profile`?

Comment: @ittus Hi. Nope, im actually taken to /terms which is weird.

Comment: Is there any console error? Can you show code of your navbar?